# How to convert semicolon separated column into a row in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

```
 Source Table: EMP_LOCATION

 NAME    LOCATION
 -------------------------------
 SMITH     NY;CA;IL;GA
 JAMES     MO;AZ;RI
 FORD      NJ
 SCOTT     TX;VA;WA;NH
 MARTIN    MD;CT

Required Output:

NAME    LOCATION
-------------------
FORD      NJ
JAMES     AZ
JAMES     MO
JAMES     RI
MARTIN    CT
MARTIN    MD
SCOTT     NH
SCOTT     TX
SCOTT     VA
SCOTT     WA
SMITH     CA
SMITH     GA
SMITH     IL
SMITH     NY
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some people will ask you to show some code, but when I needed this I spent a lot of time creating a function then I realize that I could do it with a `connect by`. So what you need is this:

```
SELECT name, REGEXP_SUBSTR (location, '[^;]+', 1, LEVEL) AS location
  FROM emp_location
 CONNECT BY 
     LEVEL <= LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE (location, '[^;]*')) + 1
  GROUP BY name, REGEXP_SUBSTR (location, '[^;]+', 1, LEVEL)
  ORDER BY name
```

Comment: @jorge-campos Wow. I haven't seen this technique before. Looks powerful. I have a question. Doesn't this only work while each location is unique to each name ? If several names were linked to the same location would it be still possible ?

Comment: @Morbo Yeah it will work for several names linked to same location. As the result is grouped you will se some location repetition. but not the names, since the group is for the name and the location.